# Firebase Functions sporadically updating doc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, webflow

I´m receiving Webhooks from an online store about categories created. The following function creates the document inside the collection `categories`

```
exports.createProductWebhookCategory = functions
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
        var category = request.body.product_type;
        try {
            const categoryRef = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc(`${category}`);
            await categoryRef.set({
                name: category,
            });
            response.status(200).send("Done");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            response.status(400).send("Error Cat");
        }
    });
```

After the category is created I'm calling an API to create an item inside Webflow. With the returned promise I get the item Id I want to store inside the previous created document

I´m trying this with 5 categories (5 webhooks) and just 1 or 2 out of 5 are updated. The other documents are not updated and do not contain the webflowId field. The updated ones change with each test run.
Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
exports.onCreateCategoryCallback = functions
    .runWith({ failurePolicy: true })
    .firestore
    .document("/categories/{categoryId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const cat = snapshot.data();
        const docId = context.params.categoryId;
        const categoryRef = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc(docId);
        try {
            const webflow_item = await webflow.createItem({
                collectionId: 'xxx',
                fields: {
                    'name': cat.name,
                    '_archived': false,
                    '_draft': false,
                },
            }, { live: true });
            console.log(`ItemId for Cat ${cat.name} is ${webflow_item._id}`);
            const doc = await categoryRef.get();
            console.log(doc.data());
            const res = await categoryRef.update({
                webflowId: webflow_item._id
            });
            console.log(`RES for ${cat.name} is: `, res);
            console.log("Function complete for cat: ", cat.name);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw 'error';
        }
    });
```

Console logs for both unsuccessful and successful update are the following

```
ItemId for Cat Coffee is 620fdc8858462f33735c986

{ name: 'Coffee' } 

RES for Coffee is:  WriteResult { 
_writeTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1645206666, _nanoseconds: 686306000 } 
} 

Function complete for cat:  Coffee
```

Comment: We can't see that you're examining an existing document with the same ID as the one you're trying to update.  For all we know, you could be looking at the wrong thing.  A screenshot that verifies the non-updated document compared to the output of the log would be helpful.  Be sure that the document ID in the log exactly matches the ID of the document on the screen.  There could even be some invisible whitespace that's causing problems.  (This is one reason why typically we don't use typed data as the IDs of documents - too easy to make a mistake. Generated IDs are better.)

Comment: I´ve added a ```const doc = await categoryRef.get(); console.log(doc.data())``` before the update. It printed out ```{ name: 'Kaffee', webflowId: '' } ``` So I guess the ref is right.

Comment: You said in some cases "nothing happens".  How are you verifying that nothing happens?  Are you looking at a document in the console?  That's what I'm getting at - we don't know what you're doing to see that nothing happens.  There might not be a bug in your code; there might be a bug in your observations.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the initial post to be more clear. Hope it's understandable now.

Comment: I guess my problem is, when I have 10 webhooks for example with 5 times Coffee as category, the webflowId is updated onCreate but afterwards the ```createProductWebhookCategory```function runs again with another webhook and deletes the webflowId. How can I pretend that? Checking for a existing doc is probably to slow when having 20+ Webhooks the same time?

Comment: @Juju If I correctly understand your problem you should only create a new Category document once. For that you should use a [Transaction](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html) in your Cloud Function that checks that no doc for this new Category already exists before creating it.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for your answer. Can I use ```doc.set(merge: true {})```as well as transactions?

Comment: @Juju Yes this would work since the ID of your document is the Category itself and the Firestore Cloud Function is triggered on creation only. But the correct approach would be to use a transaction. It is actually not very difficult, there is an [example in the doc (SDK version 8)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#web-version-8) which is not very different from your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most probably comes from the fact that you are not correctly managing the life cycle of your second Cloud Function (the Firestore triggered one).

As you will see in the three videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the official [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) you MUST return a Promise or a value in a background triggered Cloud Function when all the asynchronous operations complete. This way you indicate to the Cloud Function platform that it can shut down the instance running your Cloud Function and you also avoid this instance is shut down before the asynchronous operations are done.

Concretely, it happens sometimes that your Cloud Function is terminated before the asynchronous operations are done, because you don't return a Promise or a value at the end of your code. The other times, the Cloud Function platform does not terminate the Function immediately and the asynchronous operations can complete. You don't have any control on this behaviour and therefore it appears as an erratic behaviour and is difficult to understand/debug.

So the following adaptations should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.onCreateCategoryCallback = functions
    .runWith({ failurePolicy: true })
    .firestore
    .document("/categories/{categoryId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const cat = snapshot.data();
        // const docId = context.params.categoryId;
        // const categoryRef = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc(docId);
        
        // You can replace the two above lines by the following one
        const categoryRef = snapshot.ref; 
        
        try {
            const webflow_item = await webflow.createItem({
                collectionId: 'xxx',
                fields: {
                    'name': cat.name,
                    '_archived': false,
                    '_draft': false,
                },
            }, { live: true });
            console.log(`ItemId for Cat ${cat.name} is ${webflow_item._id}`);
            
            // Not sure why you have the two next lines?? At this stage doc.data() ===  snapshot.data()
            //const doc = await categoryRef.get();
            //console.log(doc.data());
            
            const res = await categoryRef.update({
                webflowId: webflow_item._id
            });
            console.log(`RES for ${cat.name} is: `, res);
            console.log("Function complete for cat: ", cat.name);
            
            return null;  // <== Here return a value when all the asynchronous operations complete
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }
    });
```

---

Following the comments above, the code for using a Transaction while creating the Category doc is as follows (again I didn't test it):

```
exports.createProductWebhookCategory = functions
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
        var category = request.body.product_type;
        try {

            const categoryRef = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc(`${category}`);

            await admin.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {

                return transaction.get(categoryRef).then((doc) => {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        transaction.set(categoryRef, {
                            name: category,
                        })
                    }
                });
            })
            response.status(200).send("Done");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            response.status(400).send("Error Cat");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Together with transactions that is the accepted answer! :)

Comment: @Juju Glad I could help you. See the update with the Transaction code.